# AngularJS's ngBindHtmlUnsafe blocks click events (or some weird thing)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I hope this is an easy one for someone, because it's driving me nuts. Experience the problem for yourself here: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZjRTe3p5h25RZIAUlvx?p=preview).

I want to deliver some HTML from the controller to the view. Here's the controller, which is     adapted from the example provided courtesy of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdownToggle):

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function DropdownCtrl($scope) { 
    $scope.items = [ 
        "The first choice!", 
        "And another choice for you.",  
        "but wait! A third!" 
    ];

    $scope.html = '<li class="dropdown" ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">' +
                    '<a class="dropdown-toggle">' + 
                        'Click me for a dropdown, yo!' +
                    '</a>' + 
                    '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +  
                        '<li><a>Why</a></li>' +
                        '<li><a>doesn\'t</a></li>' +
                        '<li><a>this</a></li>' +
                        '<li><a>work???</a></li>' +
                    '</ul>' + 
                   '</li>';
}
```

Nothing mind-blowing, certainly. Here's the view:

```
<h3>This works fine</h3>
<li class="dropdown" ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle">
    Click me for a dropdown, yo!
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
      <a>{{choice}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<h3>Why doesn't this work?</h3>
<div ng-controller="DropdownCtrl" ng-bind-html-unsafe="html"></div>
```

Simply put, the first dropdown works fine, as per the example provided. The second dropdown, however, does nothing. Its code is passed from the controller to the view and is delivered intact, but the dropdown doesn't drop.

Tell me someone has run into [this problem](http://plnkr.co/edit/NZjRTe3p5h25RZIAUlvx?p=preview) before.

Comment: My guess is that angular isn't "aware" it needs to process that string that was injected into there, it's just assuming that it's some HTML.  I think you may need to use a directive instead that defines a template so that angular processes it correctly, but just a guess.

Comment: That's how I discovered the problem in the first place. I am trying to pass HTML with directives from the controller to the view. The directives work as intended on their own, but as soon as you bind them to an element with ngBindHtmlUnsafe, they break. I can't even bind a click event in the directive definition itself. It's as though the containing element is blocking events.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds ludicrous but talking angular generally does.  Currently you're using a built in directive to attempt to inject code that angular needs to process.  However I believe this directive is really intended to just inject some non angular HTML into the page.  If instead you define your own directive using angular.module("myModule",[]).directive("myDirective", function()... and within the custom directive you define you put your html as the template property, then using your directive will work correctly.

Comment: That's so crazy, it just might work. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a 'compile' directive, which will take your html (no matter the source) and $compile it for you. So your view will only need:

```
<div compile="html"></div>
```

This will add html to the page instead of displaying it (like ng-bind-html does). It will find and evaluate all directives and expressions inside the html. And last but not least, it will link the scopes so you still have access to the controller.

Here is the example compile directive I pulled from the AngularJs API Docs. It uses a $watch so that it will keep compiling as the html changes.

```
.directive('compile', function($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
        function(scope) {
            // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
            return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
        },
        function(value) {
            // when the 'compile' expression changes
            // assign it into the current DOM
            element.html(value);

            // compile the new DOM and link it to the current scope.
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    );
  };
})
```

And of course for the sake of brevity here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZRye2HHX6trkq5hrz3Yb?p=preview)

Comment: Your solution with respect to the original question: http://plnkr.co/edit/pqo0YDJyWGrSIbEx5zDz?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `$scope.html` as a string, which means angular will not evaluate anything inside it or even consider it inside it's scope. In order to get angular to evaluate it to load it through a partial. This can be done by defining a template in your routes, directives or services. It can also be done by just including it. As I did in this **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VepdYWc3wsz6xMsBnVQS?p=preview)**

Comment: The string defined in the controller is being returned and compiled correctly. View the source in the Plunker HTML. There is no obvious reason why what is provided shouldn't work. If the string were the issue, you would simply see unprocessed HTML (which is what happens if you add one of these to the view: {{html}}).